# CRUD - Error When Updating MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm learning how to code php and I'm working on the CRUD. So far, I've got the Create and Delete methods working, but for the life of me, I cannot get Update to work. Am I missing something completely obvious here? Thank you in advance.

In my User class I have the following (Only related methods included here):

```
protected static $table_name="users";
protected static $db_fields = array('id', 'f_name');

public $id;
public $f_name;

public static function find_by_id($id=0) {
global $db;
$result_array = self::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM ".static::$table_name." WHERE id={$id} LIMIT 1"); 
return !empty($result_array) ? array_shift($result_array) : false;
}

protected function attributes() {
  $attributes = array();
  foreach(self::$db_fields as $field) {
    if(property_exists($this, $field)) {
      $attributes[$field] = $this->$field;
    }
  }
  return $attributes;
}

protected function sanitized_attributes() {
  global $db;
  $clean_attributes = array();
  foreach($this->attributes() as $key => $value){
    $clean_attributes[$key] = $db->escape_value($value);
  }
  return $clean_attibutes;
}

public function update() {
  global $db;
  $attributes = $this->attributes();
  $attribute_pairs = array(); 
  foreach($attributes as $key => $value) {
  $attibute_pairs[] = "{$key}='{$value}'";
  }
  $sql  = "UPDATE ".self::$table_name." SET ";
  $sql .= join(", ", $attribute_pairs);
  $sql .= " WHERE id=". $db->escape_value($this->id);
  $db->query($sql);
  if ($db->affected_rows() == 1) {
  echo "Yes!";
  } else {
  echo "No!";
  }
  }
```

In my html file, I simply have:

```
<?php 
$user = User::find_by_id(1);
$user->f_name = "UpdatedUser"; 
$user->update();
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried echoing the final query string `$sql` to make sure the variables are outputting and that the query is properly formatted?

Comment: are you sure about `$this->$field`? I would return the final update query just to be sure

Comment: Turns out this code was all correct, I just forgot and "r" in the word "attribute_pairs". I left the code above alone so you can see the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for one, your query is probably failing on account of this

```
$sql  = "UPDATE ".static::$table_name." SET ";
```

being invalid. Try:

```
$sql  = "UPDATE ".self::$table_name." SET ";
```

Comment: Also I see you've used `static::$foo` syntax elsewhere. You may want to update those as well. Here's the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) for correct usage of static keywords. Also, assuming that `$db` is a mysqli instance, I would try dumping `print_r( $db->$mysqli->error_list )` in the "no" section as it would likely give you the errors in your SQL query that prevented it from running so that you can use them to further troubleshoot ;)

Comment: Thanks, Brian. Yes, I see that error. I was playing around with static and self but even with your recommended change to all the .static to .self, it doesn't update.

Comment: Did you implement the suggestion I made about the errors from the database? Also please update your question with your current code after the changes so we can make sure we're seeing the latest rendition ;)

Comment: Thank you Brian. I've updated my code above and added the print_r( $db->$mysqli->error_list ) in the "no" section as you suggested. The message I get is "Cannot access empty property in.." the line you had me ad. What does that mean?

Comment: What is the $db global set to? I notice that's not in your code example. Can you add that to your question so we can see where you're instancing your database object onto it?

Comment: See comments, can't believe I was missing that. Thanks for your help, Brian.